# Once-weekly alarm from DCS PC1832 alarmsystem

Tags: alarm

I have a DCS PowerSeries PC1832.

[image: PC1832]

This alarm has been working fine for 10 years.

But recently, it has developed a quirk: **every Wednesday, at 10:07am exactly, the alarm goes off**. First the long beep, and then the outside horn blasts the alarm, unless I cancel it.

My wife thinks it may have been the result of her trying to program daylight-savings time, and getting it wrong?

We checked the manual, but no mention of a weekly alarm feature?

I mean.. how would that even be useful?

Why does my alarm go off, once a week, at Wed 10:07 am?

### Update

Battery (when disconnected) measures 13.6V and was replaced not too long ago.

There are no wireless sensors.

When I do `*6 [CODE] *` I hear a long beep, and nothing on the display, other than this finger on keypad icon:

[image: keypadicon]

### Update 2

When I do `*2` I see nothing on the display. A hazard light will flash orange:

[image: warning flashing]

### Update 3

The issue was auto-arm.

Comment: Low battery?  Has the battery ever been replaced?

Comment: It looks like a multi-zone alarm. What zone is tripping and what kind of sensors are on that zone? Or is it a tamper zone? Be as specific as possible. Please provide more detail. Best to add the info to your question by editing the question.

Comment: Most likely the battery crapping out with old age. When you replace it, date it. If you have any wireless zones, those all have batteries at the sensors, but my typical experience of a system like this one is that nobody has ever thought to replace that 4.5AH 12V lead acid gel cell, and they do **not** live forever. Mind you, it should be giving a trouble code, but perhaps it's gone past the point of that, or it somehow thinks setting the alarm off is a trouble code.

Comment: you might need a factory reset and then reprogram it

Comment: It's supposed to have a "500 event buffer" so what events are stored most recently? From an LCD Keypad *6[mastercode] then * should bring that up. Trouble codes should be *2 - and BTW - any 4.5AH (or more) 12V lead acid gel cell will work - don't overpay for one "for an alarm" they are pretty much all the same, other than profit margin for the seller.

Comment: Second the advice to check the log to find out which sensor(s) are reporting the issue. Vibration can be enough to set off marginal sensors; a power surge can be enough to set off marginal systems. What, if anything, is different on Wednesday at around that time -- an exercise routine, perhaps?

Comment: Two separate things you seem to have combined: (feel free to look these up on your own plenty of resources out there) *2 is for trouble codes. *6[mastercode] then * is for the event log.

Comment: Log shmog, *while* the alarm is alarming and immediately after you clear it doesn't the display identify the fault?????

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I refer to the PDF [installation manual](https://cms.dsc.com/download.php?t=1&id=17007). Any terms that I use here may be found in the manual by doing a string search. The system may have inadvertently been set to Auto-Arm once a week, every week. To turn off Auto-Arm, perform this sequence from the manual’s page 8, PDF page 11:

*6[code]2 then scroll from *enable* to *disable* then press * and listen for the tone. If you get 3 beeps, it is still set to Auto-Arm. If you get a steady 2-second tone, Auto-Arm is disabled. The Auto-Arm day and time can be found and changed if you wish in *6[code]3 *make changes*, then *

If this doesn't work, you may also wish to look at the Delinquency functions. The system can send a report to the central station if the alarm has not been set for X days or minutes where X is 1-255 and days or minutes are selected in another parameter. Similarly, a delinquency can occur if a particular zone has not been tripped for 1-255 days or minutes, such as by opening a door or walking through a room.

Note that I am not referring to RF Delinquency, a different thing entirely.

Comment: Auto-Arm once a week would certainly do it, assuming that the house is locked up solid at the time.

Comment: Thank you. My LCD unit does not scroll options on the display, but I tried `*6 CODE 2` to try turning off the auto-arm. I'm pretty sure this will have solved it, but will report back next week if it was indeed silent on Wed 10:07.

Comment: @Bram See manual page 10 (PDF page 13) for scrolling instructions. Use the < > keys to scroll. If you got one 2-second beep at the end, it's turned off. Three beeps and it's still on. Auto-Arm can turn *itself* on if a late closing time monitor has been inadvertently set or if motion zones have seen no motion for a certain time, all programmable. Come on, admit it, you stole this alarm system from Tiffany & Co., didn't you? ;-)